# Give an example to show we cannot replace $q\in \Bbb Q$ when proving $f+g$ is measurable

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let $f:E\to \Bbb R$ and $g:E\to \Bbb R $ be measurable real-valued functions, I'm given the proof of $f+g$ is measurable as the following:

> Let $r$ be any real number. If $f(x)+g(x)\gt r$, then $\exists$ a rational number $q$ such that $r-g(x)\lt q \lt f(x)$. It follows that 
>   $$\{x\in E: (f+g)(x)\gt r\}=\bigcup_{q\in \Bbb Q}\{x\in E:f(x)\gt q\}\bigcap\{x\in E: g(x)\gt r-q\}$$
>   Hence, $f+g$ is a measurable function.

Could someone give an example to show that in this proof, we cannot replace $q\in \Bbb Q$ by $q\in \Bbb Z$? Thanks.

Comment: Rather an example, just notice that if we replaced $q$ with an integer, the statement does not hold in general. The density of the rationals is essential in this proof, so that we can guarantee that there exists a real number in between $r - g(x), f(x)$. Moreover, we wanted to choose this collection of real numbers so that it was countable, since measurability works nice with countable.

Comment: If $f(x)=1$, $g(x)=0.3$ and $r=1.2$, where is the integer $q$ such that $r-g(x)\lt q \lt f(x)$, i.e., $1.2-0.3=0.9<q<1$?

Comment: Just a little simpler: Imagine $f(x) = 3.2$, $g(x) = 0$, $r = \pi$. There is no $q\in\mathbb Z$ such that $\pi < q < 3.2$.